# Karl Strauss Aurora Hoppyalis Clone?

Tags: recipe, ipa, americanipa

Does anyone have a Karl Strauss Aurora Hoppyalis clone?  This is an outstanding beer and I would love to try to make it.

Comment: Their website gives you the foundations to attempt a clone.

STATS
ABV: 7.0%
Color: 4 SRM
Bitterness: 60 IBU
TASTING NOTES
Style: San Diego-Style IPA
Malt: Pale Malt, White Wheat
Hops: Simcoe, Mosaic, Amarillo, Citra

Answer (score 2):

I found this clone on Brewer's Friend:

Boil size 3Gal

Efficiency 65%

OG: 1066 FG: 1012

**Grains**

4lb American Pale 2Row

1lb American White Wheat

0.55lb Cane Sugar (late addition)

**Mash**

145F for 90 min

**Hops**

0.25oz Simcoe 60min

0.5oz Amarillo 20min

0.5oz Mosaic 5min

0.5oz Citra 0min

**Yeast**

Safale US-05 fermenting at 60F